# Clustering with data visualization

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, data-visualization, business-intelligence, knime

The format of my input file is the following:

```
PERSON1 BUILDING1
PERSON2 BUILDING4
PERSON3 BUILDING4
PERSON5 BUILDING3
PERSON3 BUILDING2
PERSON3 BUILDING1
PERSON5 BUILDING6
PERSON4 BUILDING6
1000 more rows like this
```

Each row should be read like this "the person X visited building Y"

I simply want to have clusters like this:

```
Cluster 1 : Persons that visited only 1 building (the same building)
Cluster 2 : Persons that visited only 2 buildings (the same buildings, let's say building 1 & 2)
Cluster 3 : Persons that visited only 2 buildings (the same buildings, let's say building 3 & 4)
Cluster 4 : Persons that visited only 3 buildings (the same buildings)
etc..
```

What would be the best way to do it? Is there a software ideally with data visualization that can do that? I tried Knime with no success.

Comment: Have you also tried the network mining extension of KNIME https://www.knime.com/book/network-visualization ?

Comment: Yes, I tried the network mining extension and went through the examples of KNIME but couldn't achieve what I want to do.

Comment: Would you be open to a solution in R?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reformat your data appropriately.

The use a **group_by** operation based on the set of buildings visited.

This is much simpler than clustering.

Answer (score 0):

I second @Anony-Mousse the solutions is more similar to use "group by" than make a clustering. So, with the idea to prove it works I built a [simple code with knime](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W7k5nWqNYvRTbzbGrSfZFFC1fc5u0rWE/view?usp=sharing) getting the expected result. Then, for the visualization part you mention, maybe a correspondence analysis could be usuful, .

[image]

this chart is implemented in R (you can use R node) and shows how related is a entity (let's say visitors-blue) to another entity (let's say buildings-red) but ofcourse, the proper chart depends on your full data and intentions.